# Install apk file in Android

Tags: android, arcgis, android-install-apk

I've been for the past 2 hours trying everything to install an apk in my android phone but I couldn't find a solution...

I've implemented an `ArcGIS app with Sherlock Action Bars`. My project as a `minimum SDK Version 7`, and `my phone is a Android 2.3.3 (SDK Version 10)`. The phone is an `Acer Z110 Duo`.

My manifest is:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.AEP41.main"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.AEP41.main.AEP41Activity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FieldDetails"
        android:description="@string/title_activity_field_details"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

There is something that I'm missing? Is there any settings that I need to change in my phone to install it?

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Does your phone support this? `<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />`

And what is the installation error?

Comment: whats your error.?? put logcat..

Comment: @Bigflow I've tried put this requirement to false and it did't work.

Comment: @Segi I've exported the Eclipse project to unsigned application package and copied to my phone... The only error that appears is "Application not installed".

Comment: Uninstall the previous version first on your phone, before trying to install the exported apk

Comment: It's the first time that I tried to install it. There is no old version.

Comment: download and install: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.dama.hardwareinfo (or other program which can show you your device specs) then check if your phone supports opengl es 2.0

Comment: You also didn't test/start the application on the phone through eclipse? (many forget this, that this is also kind of a installation).

Comment: You can't install an **unsigned** APK on the phone. It **must be signed**

Comment: check your settings for installing unsigned apk. it is checked or not..

Comment: @Selvin I've already run the program and it appears both OpenGl 1.X and OpenGl 2.0

Comment: @Bigflow I've already tested the app in a Sony Tablet using Eclipse and it worked fine and without any errors.

Comment: @DavidWasser You can install unsigned app if you activate the unknown sources in your settings, witch I did...

Comment: @Segi I've checked the unknown sources in my settings...

Comment: @ManuelPires No, you can't. But I see you've already gotten that information again from viduka.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

David Wasser is right - app must be signed. "Unknown sources" is for apps from other markets then Google Play. So export signed APK or build project and find signed APK in *bin* folder of project.

Comment: Thanks a lot... I thought that if you exported as unsigned project you could installed... But searching in bin project folder of the project it worked.

Answer (score 1):

To allow app installs from non-Market apps, tap the menu button on your home screen, then choose Settings >> Applications >> Unknown sources.

Comment: After that, you can use a software like "APK Installer". Indeed, you have to export your project via tools like Eclipse. After that, you upload it online with something like DROPBOX. You download it in your telephone & then you can open it with APK Installer & install it ;)